# How can i TextField show cursor always

Tags: flutter

I want show cursor always in textfield but i couldn't see a solution.
What I want to do is always show the cursor like whatsapp.
I want the cursor to appear even if the keyboard is closed

```
TextField(
  textCapitalization:TextCapitalization.sentences,
  minLines: 1,
  maxLines: 6,
  controller: _textEditingController,
  focusNode: _focusNode,
)
```

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. What do you mean by always show the cursor?

Comment: I want the cursor to appear even if the keyboard is closed

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
TextField(
  textCapitalization:TextCapitalization.sentences,
  minLines: 1,
  maxLines: 6,
  autofocus: true,                            // line Added
  controller: _textEditingController,
  focusNode: _focusNode,
)
```